# How to convert two class generic?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics

I have two classes PostSM and Post and A BaseService class. My BaseService class is a generic class and get two types of class TEntity and TServiceModel. This class convert TServiceModel to TEntity and save it in database. My Problem is that how to convert TServiceModel to TEntity. I explicity convert Post to PostSM and PostSM to Post int PostSM class.

```
public class PostSM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public RowVersion string { get; set; }
    
    public static explicit operator PostSM(Post post)
    {
        if (post == null)
            return null;
        else
        {
            PostSM postSM = new PostSM()
            {
                Id = post.Id,
                Title = post.Title,
                Body = post.Body,
                RowVersion = post.RowVersion
            };

            return postSM;
        }
    }

    public static explicit operator Post(PostSM postSM)
    {
        if (postSM == null)
            return null;
        else
        {
            Post post = new Post()
            {
                Id = postSM.Id,
                Title = postSM.Title,
                Body = postSM.Body,
                RowVersion = postSM.RowVersion
            };

            return post;
        }
    }
}


public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a class with name BaseService

```
public class BaseService<TServiceModel, TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
    where TServiceModel : class
{
    public virtual TServiceModel Add(TServiceModel serviceModel)
    {
        try
        {
            TEntity entity = (TEntity)serviceModel;
            //var addedEntity = repo.Add(entity);
            //uow.SaveChanges();

            return serviceModel;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }   
}
```

In Add Method in BaseService class, as I mentioned at first of the question I need to convert PostSM to Post, but because BaseService is a generic class, I don't know how to do it.

```
TEntity entity = (TEntity)servieMoel;
```

I get error for this line in my Add method.

Comment: When I copy and paste your code into a empty project I get a ton of syntax errors. Can you please post code that I can copy, paste, and (mostly) compile? I want to be able to work with your code and then post a solution. I generally don't post anything unless I can get it to compile.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes you are right. I edit my question

Comment: Something like ```where TEntity : Base``` ?

Comment: @MichaelMao I edit my question. It would be your kindness to look at it again

Comment: ```static explicit operator``` is essential to you?

Comment: Yes I use them to cast my model between layers of project. @MichaelMao

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look at the AutoMapper library (or something similar). Using tools like that is, as far as I know, the common practice when it comes to converting database models to service models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actuall you cannot do it, nothing is known about your generic Types TEntity and TServiceModel, so there is no other operation allowed than assignments.

instead of an operator you should use an interface, for your TServiceModel.
like

```
interface IConvert<TTo>
{
     TTo Convert()
}
```

Implement this interface in your class PostSM

```
class PostSM : IConvert<Post>
{
    public Post Convert() => (Post)this;
    // or put your explicit operator code here
}
```

And finally put a constraint on your implementation

```
public class BaseService<TServiceModel, TEntity>
        where TEntity : class
        where TServiceModel : class, IConvert<TEntity>
```

And this will allow you to call

```
TEntity entity = serviceModel.Convert();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the cleanest option here is simple inheritance.

```
public class PostSM : Post { }

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public class BaseService<TServiceModel, TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
    where TServiceModel : TEntity
{
    public virtual TServiceModel Add(TServiceModel serviceModel)
    {
        TEntity entity = (TEntity)serviceModel;
        //var addedEntity = repo.Add(entity);
        //uow.SaveChanges();

        return serviceModel;
    }
}
```